# How to run Android command on cygwin

Tags: android, command-line, terminal, cygwin

I want run android related commands from cygwin. I am able to run adb related commands but I am not able to run commands like "android", what package is to be installed on cygwin ?

I want run android commands like, on windows cmd, if I run command  "android " it will launch android sdk manager. In same way I want run on cygwin.

android.bat does not worked

Comment: can you elaborate more please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `android.bat` alone, it will pop up the SDK manager, as you've found. You need to provide additional arguments. For example, `android.bat -h` should show you usage info.